# is there a word describe an emotion that is happy with luck?

Tags: word-usage

Is there a word describe that i am happy on my mind, cause I thought i was so lucky.

For example, in a class, the teacher picked a person to answer a very difficult question. when she picked someone not me, I am so happy that it is not me, and thought that i am really a lucky person. But I just thought it on my mind, did not express and share with others.

Comment: The emotion you experience in such situations is ***relief*** (that someone else was chosen, not you).

Comment: I don't think relief serves both conditions, even when relief and happy are taken in isolation. Otherwise the expression happy and relieved would leave one or the other redundant.

Comment: Another lovely word in this context is **serendipity** -  the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way.

Comment: @BruceMurray: But "happy and relieved" ***does*** leave one or the other redundant in most contexts! Though not so much as "happy and content", which is actually a [far more common collocation.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy+and+relieved%2Chappy+and+content&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappy%20and%20relieved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chappy%20and%20content%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: yeah, although relief seems understandable in this sentence, but the concentration of situation want to emphasize the thinking of ‘i am lucky’, and with the happy mood. Not exactly emphasizing the removal of anxiety or fear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word "**relieved**" would fit there. It doesn't exactly mean "happy", but it means removal of the anxiety or fear that I would be asked a question I couldn't answer. "Relieved" is the past participle of "relieve", which is the verb form of "relief".

[Merriam-Webster "relief"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relief)
2a removal or lightening of something oppressive, painful, or distressing